# nineoldandroids - setDuration doesnt work on AnimatorSet

Tags: android, android-animation, nineoldandroids

I have the following code which splits an image in half and animate each part in different direction:

```
final AnimatorSet mSetAnim = new AnimatorSet();
final Animator topAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(topImage, "translationY", (bmp.getHeight() / 2) * -1);
final Animator bottomAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bottomImage, "translationY", bmp.getHeight() / 2);
mSetAnim.setDuration(duration); 
mSetAnim.playTogether(topAnim, bottomAnim);
mSetAnim.start();
```

I'm using NineOldAndroids in order to support old android versions but for some reason no matter what value i put in 'duration' it doesnt seem to have any affect. The animation duration stays the same - half a second more or less.

When i use android's animation apis i can see that the duration is changing.

Any idea how to workarround this ?

Comment: Using `mSetAnim.getDuration()`, Try printing in a toast to see what value exists at runtime and comment.

Comment: Use `mSetAnim.setDuration(duration);` after playTogether() as is done in http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: @MohammedAli Ya habibi, it worked ! also just fyi mSetAnim.getDuration() was returning -1. Add an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mSetAnim.getDuration()`, Try printing in a toast to see what value exists at runtime.

Use `mSetAnim.setDuration(duration)`; after `playTogether()` as is done in [nineoldandroids.com](http://nineoldandroids.com/).